# ngClass on many elements makes site very slow

Tags: angular, listener, angular6

I'm currently making a tree-view in my Angular 6 application, which I got working (nested and everything). One of the problems I encounter, is that when my page has many elements (a couple of thousand) and they all have `[ngClass]` on them (to show different colors depending on the selected node), the page tends to hang a lot. I've created a StackBlitz to show my problem: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-atveai

To test it out, simply hold down the arrow up/down keys on the right output screen. It should be very slow. If you set the loop to only show 100 elements instead of 10000, it works flawlessly (because less elements).

To catch the keydown event (which I want on my document), I do this:

```
@Component({
  host: {
    '(document:keydown)': 'handleKeyboardEvent($event)'
  }
})
```

This calls the `handleKeyboardEvent()` with the `$event` object.

In the HTML file, I have a very simple `*ngFor`, where each element has a `[ngClass]="GetClass(item)"`. Basically this returns an object that contains all the classes that should be applied. In my case, if the selected node equals the element, it sets `obj["selected"] = true`, so that one element will get the `selected` class.

This is quite demanding, I would imagine, because each element calls this method a lot of times. That would be my guess as to why this is slow.

My page can easily have between 5000 and 10000 nodes (something we really don't want to change, if there's a way to fix this). However, the amount of root nodes are probably between 10 and 30. Many of the nodes are nested as children (basically 99% of them are nested).

My thought would be to stop `[ngClass]` from listening to changes, if the parent node is **NOT** expanded. Not expanded = not shown on the page anyway.

So the real question is: Is it possible to stop elements from listening to changes, if a condition is met? And if so, would it even help? As that would basically introduce another listener, which wouldn't really solve anything.

Comment: It isn't slow for me, so I can't test it. Try 1) returning the same object instead of instantiating a new one every time. 2) Don't call a function at all, calculate the stuff in template. 3) Try using getters instead of a normal function. Either of those should make it run faster. Angular will call function every change detection cycle and instantiate and garbage collect those objects every time.

Comment: 4) Style it in handleKeyboardEvent method, so you have just one function call on document.

Comment: @ritaj Just making sure: You are indeed holding down the arrow keys for a few seconds, then letting go, right? On my PC (i7-7700k and 32GB RAM) and the rest of our PCs at the office, it doesn't scroll through like it does with 100 elements.

Comment: Oh right, I have set it to 1000 and it worked, but at around 3000 it starts working slow.

Comment: Okay, so it seems like when I don't create a new object each time, it works pretty damn well. However, my GetClass has a bit of logic, that basically checks if my node has a state and so on (which is why I'm returning an object). Here's an example, where each node also has a state to display a color: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vqfpte

Comment: In the above example, if I were to reuse the objects, I would basically have to create one for each case (if state==failed && selected, if state==completed && selected, if state==failed, AND if state==completed). And I have quite a few states, haha

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't seem like a good solution. I tried to handle styling in handleKeyboardEvent, but it's still slow because of document.querySelector. I'll try with using ViewChildren now.

Comment: @ritaj Here's an example (that unfortunately doesn't work): https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vqfpte - I made an object for each of the states possible, and it's a bit faster but still very slow :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I got it *kinda* working like this:

1) Use change detection OnPush

```
@Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
      host: {
        '(document:keydown)': 'handleKeyboardEvent($event)'
      },
      changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
    })
```

2) Use template interpolation instead of function calls

```
<span class="{{item.state === 'failed' ? 'failed' : 'completed'}} {{item.ordering === selected ? 'selected' : ''}}">{{item.name}}</span>
```

It works fast with 5000 rows, but it's still sluggish with 10000. Best I could do, unfortunately.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1sg1mh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Using the ChangeDetectionStragety.OnPush definitely increased performance a lot! And simply parsing in the classes accordingly based on the states, is also a lot faster than [ngClass]. Thanks a lot - it works fine with 5000+ elements now!

Comment: Just wanted to say, replacing `ngClass` with `class` + template interpolation was the winner for me. I just took a ridiculously slow template (locking the UI thread for up to a minute) down to 15ms rendering time :) Change detection was already set to `OnPush` and didn't help much so I was surprised and delighted to find that interpolation is so effective! Thanks!!